# PHP 5.6 (xampp) is showing warnings instead of throwing ArgumentCountError

Tags: windows, command-line, php, xampp

I am running some php scripts from cli. I use xampp installation for php with path var /c/xampp/php. I tend to swap versions around by renaming installed xampp folders when I want to switch between php5 and 7 etc..

Recently deleted my php5.6 and had to reinstall it. Now for some reason I can run any funciton without passing in the required params and I only get a warning instead of an exception halting executuin.

eg.

```
    <?php
function someFunction($required_param){
    if (!isset($required_param)) die('WTF! Param was not passed in yet im allowed to execute!');
}
someFunction();
```

//results with

```
$ php test/test.php
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for someFunction(), called in C:\repo\php5\orm\test\test.php on line 5 and defined in C:\repo\php5\orm\test\test.php on line 2

Warning: Missing argument 1 for someFunction(), called in C:\repo\php5\orm\test\test.php on line 5 and defined in C:\repo\php5\orm\test\test.php on line 2
WTF! Param was not passed in!
```

This is really strange behaviour. I have never seen php allow a function to be called without the required params.

Any ideas how this could happen?

PS-also note that it outputs the error twice even if I disable log errors or display errors to only get a single error output. (the above example is without setting any error handling at run time just what you see is run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior versions of PHP raised a warning when encountered ArgumentCountError.

Now, at least from v7.1 it raises an Error exception.

[PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php)